# How to make part of css spritesheet scale div element?

Tags: html, css, sprite-sheet

I have a div element, and a spritesheet. The div element size is 25x25, and the part of the sprite sheet I want for the div background is from (0,0) with a width of 27 and height of 30.

Also I want that part of the image to stretch and fit the div.

I have this css for the div:

```
background:url('engineer.png');
background-size: 100%;
width:25px;
height:25px;
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Could you create a fiddle?

Comment: What's your HTML markup?